# Pass the `where` object to a dynamic GraphQL query

Tags: graphql

Say I have the following query:

```
Foo($account: String!) {
  foo(where: { account: $account }) {
    id
    bar
  }
}
```

All good for now, but can I replace the `$account: String!` parameter with something like this:

```
Foo($where: Object!) {
  foo(where: $where) {
    id
    bar
  }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to specify the exact input object type that `where` is. What that type is depends on the schema you're querying against.

So if you're schema is

```
type Query {
  foo(where: FooWhere!): Foo
}

input FooWhere {
  account: String
}
```

Your query becomes

```
Foo($where: FooWhere!) {
  foo(where: $where) {
    id
    bar
  }
}
```

If you're querying some third-party API, they should either provide documentation or expose a GraphiQL or GraphQL Playground interface where you can look up the appropriate type to use.